# How we configure reactotron with reduxjs/tookkit?

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit

I want to configure https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ with https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron,

I try below steps but not working
https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/plugin-redux.md

Answer (score 11, accepted):

finally done by following using enhancer

```
configureStore({
    reducer: RootReducer,
    enhancers: [reactotron.createEnhancer()]
})
```

==================================

reactotron file

```
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import { reactotronRedux } from 'reactotron-redux';

const reactotron = Reactotron.configure({
    name: 'My app name',
    host: '192.168.1.8'
})
    
    .useReactNative({

        asyncStorage: false, // there are more options to the async storage.
        networking: {
            // optionally, you can turn it off with false.
            ignoreUrls: /symbolicate/,
        },
        editor: false, // there are more options to editor
        overlay: false // just turning off overlay
    })
    .use(reactotronRedux())
    .connect();

export default reactotron;
```

Answer (score 1):

[**--Reference--**](https://dev.to/ajmal_hasan/reactotron-setup-in-react-native-redux-applications-4jj3)

Step 1:
Install:

`npm i --save-dev reactotron-react-js && npm install --save-dev reactotron-redux`

**Step 2:
Create ReactotronConfig.js**

```
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-js";
import { reactotronRedux } from "reactotron-redux";

const reactotron = Reactotron.configure({ name: "MERN" }) // we can use plugins here -- more on this later
  .use(reactotronRedux())
  .connect(); // let's connect!

export default reactotron;
```

**Step 3:
Add enhancer in redux store:**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import AuthReducer from "./features/authSlice";
import TourReducer from "./features/tourSlice";
import reactotron from "./config/ReactotronConfig";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: AuthReducer,
    tour: TourReducer,
  },
  ...(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && {
    enhancers: [reactotron.createEnhancer()],
  }),
});
```

Step 4:
Open Reactotron App and refresh the webpage.
[image]